# Rails+ActiveAdmin - filtering with ransacker throws an error PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near ","

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, ransack

I have a project on Ruby on Rails 4.1.4, using `activeadmin 1.0.0.pre from git://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin`, `pg 0.17.1`, PostgreSQL 9.3

In the project I have these models:

1. `class User
      has_one :account`
2. `class Account
         belongs_to :user
         has_many :project_accounts
         has_many :projects, :through => :project_accounts`
3. `class Project
         # the project has a boolean attribute 'archive'
         has_many :project_accounts`
4. `class ProjectAccount
         belongs_to :account
         belongs_to :project`

I've got a task to implement an ActiveAdmin filter on the index page, called "by_active_projects", so it has to show the users that have defined number of active projects, that means such projects that have `archive == false`.
E.g. if I type '2' in the filter, it has to find such accounts that have exactly 2 active projects.

For now I have registered "Account" resource in ActiveAdmin, and within `admin/account.rb` i've added `filter :by_active_projects_eq`

After that I've defined a scope `having_active_projects` for Account model (models/account.rb):

```
scope :having_active_projects, ->(number) { joins(:projects).where("projects.archive = ?", false).having("count(projects) = ?", number).group("accounts.id") }
```

Next step, I've defined a ransacker for Account model like this:

```
ransacker :by_active_projects, formatter: proc{ |v|
    data = Account.having_active_projects(v).map(&:id)
    data ||= nil
  } do |parent|
    parent.table[:id]
  end
```

In the development DB there is one account, that has exactly 8 active projects, and filtering works great for it. But when I've tried to filter accounts by 2 active projects, I faced an error. In the DB there are three such accounts, and the error page reported me that the query syntax is wrong:

```
SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT 1 AS count_column FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "accounts"."id" = 'e4d247ec-e64d-4e8a-996a-4d73ccb11257', 'bcb8fa61-4a53-4b45-8954-8fb6ae328365', '93d670b6-7b8f-4c27-91cc-e0f44c137114' LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count
```

As you can see, instead of

```
"accounts"."id" IN ('e4d247ec-e64d-4e8a-996a-4d73ccb11257', 'bcb8fa61-4a53-4b45-8954-8fb6ae328365', '93d670b6-7b8f-4c27-91cc-e0f44c137114')
```

this thing is being generated:

```
"accounts"."id" = 'e4d247ec-e64d-4e8a-996a-4d73ccb11257', 'bcb8fa61-4a53-4b45-8954-8fb6ae328365', '93d670b6-7b8f-4c27-91cc-e0f44c137114'
```

I tried to dig down into the source code, moving with breakpoints on the pieces of code within the ActiveRecord, ActiveAdmin and Ransack lib's and figured out that the relation is being constructed with the help of ***Arel::Nodes::Equality***. I'm not sure this is the reason but one I can say for sure:

**lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb**
`

```
560   def where!(opts = :chain, *rest)
561      if opts == :chain
562        WhereChain.new(self)
563      else
564        references!(PredicateBuilder.references(opts)) if Hash === opts
565        self.where_values += build_where(opts, rest)
566        self
567      end
568    end`
```

`self` here is an Active Record relation for Account;

before calling `build_where` on the row #565, `self.to_sql` equals to

```
SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts"  WHERE "accounts"."deleted_at" IS NULL  ORDER BY "accounts"."created_at" desc
```

after calling it and assigning the result to `self.where_values`,

`self.to_sql` equals to

```
SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts"  WHERE "accounts"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "accounts"."id" = 'e4d247ec-e64d-4e8a-996a-4d73ccb11257', 'bcb8fa61-4a53-4b45-8954-8fb6ae328365', '93d670b6-7b8f-4c27-91cc-e0f44c137114'  ORDER BY "accounts"."created_at" desc
```

Any help or information on the matter is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I found the solution:

First, I've changed my filter in `admin/account.rb` from

```
filter :by_active_projects_eq
```

to

```
filter :by_active_projects_in,
         :as => :string
```

This approach resulted in correct SQL generation,

```
"accounts"."id" IN ('e4d247ec-e64d-4e8a-996a-4d73ccb11257', 'bcb8fa61-4a53-4b45-8954-8fb6ae328365', '93d670b6-7b8f-4c27-91cc-e0f44c137114')
```

After that I also had to change my ransacker from

```
ransacker :by_active_projects, formatter: proc{ |v|
    data = Account.having_active_projects(v).map(&:id)
    data ||= nil
  } do |parent|
    parent.table[:id]
  end
```

to

```
ransacker :by_active_projects, formatter: proc{ |v|
    data = Account.having_active_projects(v).pluck(:id)
    data.present? ? data : nil
  } do |parent|
    parent.table[:id]
  end
```

because the way it was implemented also caused incorrect query: for example there are no such accounts that have exactly 5 active projects. In that case

```
data = Account.having_active_projects(v).pluck(:id)
```

returned "Empty Array", and dealing with this Array with `data ||= nil` never actually returned `nil`, and that resulted in SQL like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "accounts"  WHERE "accounts"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "accounts"."id" IN () LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count
```

notice the `"accounts"."id" IN ()` part, that was causing trouble.

After replacing `data ||= nil` with `data.present? ? data : nil`, if `data` was not present it was assigned a `nil`, and that part in SQL was generated corectly: `"accounts"."id" IN (NULL)`